# Is it possible to redefine __eq__ function in __main__ from script?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to make `__eq__` function in `__main__` always return True. It should be something like this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return True
```

Is it possible to write any python script that do this? So i want to run this cool script and after that my Interpreter should always return `True`  when i do equality comparison (until restart):

```
1==2
True
```

Comment: No, you can't do that - each object implements equality separately. You could patch the built-ins with e.g. https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit, but I don't know if this works for "magic methods". Also, why would you *want* to do this? It seems likely to break quite a lot of stuff.

Comment: In fact I want to solve this task https://www.checkio.org/mission/solution-for-anything/ and I don't know how to do this in another way than i've described.

Comment: Ah, I see; you don't **need** to make everything equal! Note that e.g. `x == y` calls `x.__eq__(y)` *before* anything else, and that `1==2` **isn't** a test case you need to match.

Comment: Ohh)) thanks a lot! It was so easy, i was confused it's "Challenging" level of difficulty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the requirement in the question isn't for *all objects* to implement all comparisons as truth-y, it's for *whatever `checkio` returns* to do so. Here's one very simple implementation:

```
class Steamroller(object):

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

    __lt__ = __gt__ = __ge__ = __le__ = __ne__ = __eq__


def checkio(*dont, **care):
    return Steamroller()
```

Irrespective of the arguments you pass to `checkio` you get a `Steamroller` back, and irrespective of the comparison you then make with it it will `return True`. See e.g. [the data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) for more on implementing comparisons.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help! But maybe it's not very good to post exact answer for this problem?